# Can one person say Kaddish for two different deceased people?

Tags: halacha, death, kaddish

Can one person say Kaddish for someone at the same time he is saying Kaddish for his parent?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, even the same *kadish*, according to [*Gesher Hachayim* 30:8:8](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=31174&st=&pgnum=293&hilite=). However, for a practical ruling, [CYLOR](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/CYLOR).

Answer (score 3):

I recall hearing a psak on a Rabbi Rakeffet shiur that as long as it's one Kaddish per person per day.  So if a person says Kaddish six times per day, he could do it for up to six different people.

Answer (score 3):

The Kitzur Shulchan Aruch in [סימן כו - דיני קדיש יתום](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html#HtmpReportNum0025_L2) says:

> **סעיף ט"ז:**  מִי שֶׁהוּא אָבֵל עַל אָבִיו, וְגַם עַל אִמּוֹ, מִכָּל מָקוֹם, אֵין לוֹ זְכוּת יוֹתֵר בִּתְפִלּוֹת וְקַדִּישִׁים מִשְּׁאָר אָבֵל, מִשּׁוּם **דְּזִכָּרוֹן אֶחָד עוֹלֶה לְכָאן וּלְכָאן**. (כנ"י) ועַיֵּן נוב"ה סִימָן ה.

So as far as parents are concerned, one Kaddish *covers* both of them.